# Using a div to confirm AND submit a form

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, submit, confirm

I have the following code:

```
<div class="ui-button-submit" onclick="document.forms['appointment-form'].submit();"><img src="/laravel/public/img/icon-delete.png"><span class="ui-button-text"> Mass Delete</span></div>
```

In my form I have a few checkboxes which I can click and then hit this button (the above code) to submit and delete those records. The thing is, I need to have a confirmation message in the above code, so it asks for a confirmation before submitting the form. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste your submit() code please.......

Comment: Can you display the html form please, thank you.

Comment: There is no more code for that. This is it. onclick="document.forms['appointment-form'].submit();" -> This submits the form. And the form itself is a simple HTML form.

Comment: "the form" where is the form? I'm asking you to display the source code for **"the form"** you are referring to. If you don't have a form then obviously this isn't going to work as you don't have a form to submit.

Comment: I apologize, I stated my question wrong. Edited it now. The forum submit works. The only thing I need is a confirmation before submitting. I'm sorry for being vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show confirm box before submitting the form. 
So , first change the form submit method call, **when you click on Mass Delete button show Confirm dialogue using JavaScript**, then  user click on OK or YES button then submit the form(call your method document.forms['appointment-form'].submit()).

Comment: That actually makes sense and I haven't thought about it like that, thanks :)